# Flutter, one time dialog inside initState

Tags: flutter

i have a problem. I want to create a one time dialog inside initState but i don't know how. I have seen numerous guides but none are for me. I need to create the one time dialog in the initState without dealing with the rest of the code. How can I do? Can anyone help me? I leave the code below

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
      final int dialogOpen = prefs.getInt('dialog_open') ?? 0;
      if (dialogOpen == 0) {//show dialog for one time only
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {

          // TO DO ONE TIME DIALOG

          prefs.setInt("dialog_open", 1);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I want to create a popup that appears only once to the user. That code now displays nothing. I would like an "example" text that appears only once to the user and asks for confirmation.

EDIT: I have tried this (INSIDE //TO DO) but it doesn't work:

```
showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) => AlertDialog(title: Text("Dialog title")),
            );
```

RIEDIT: I post the whole class for better help

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_browser/app_bar/browser_app_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter_browser/models/webview_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_browser/webview_tab.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'models/browser_model.dart';
import 'package:new_version/new_version.dart';

class Browser extends StatefulWidget {
  Browser({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BrowserState createState() => _BrowserState();
}

class _BrowserState extends State<Browser> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isdialogShown = true;
  late SharedPreferences _prefs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getIntentData();

    final newVersion = NewVersion(
      iOSId: 'com.google.onepiecepower',
      androidId: 'com.app.onepiecepower',
    );
    newVersion.showAlertIfNecessary(context: context);

    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
      _prefs = prefs;
      isdialogShown = prefs.getBool('dialog_open') ?? false;
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  void showDialogWidget() {
    if (!isdialogShown) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Dialog title"),
              content: Text("This is my message."),
              actions: [
                okButton,
              ],
          ),
        );
      });
      isdialogShown = true;
      _prefs.setBool('dialog_open',isdialogShown);
    }
  }

  Widget okButton = TextButton(
    child: Text("OK"),
    onPressed: () { },
  );

  getIntentData() async {
    showDialogWidget();
    var browserModel = Provider.of<BrowserModel>(context, listen: false);
    browserModel.addTab(WebViewTab(
      key: GlobalKey(),
      webViewModel: WebViewModel(url: Uri.parse("http://onepiecepower.info")),
    ));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    precacheImage(AssetImage("assets/icon/icon.png"), context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildBrowser();
  }

  Widget _buildBrowser() {
    var currentWebViewModel = Provider.of<WebViewModel>(context, listen: true);
    var browserModel = Provider.of<BrowserModel>(context, listen: true);

    browserModel.addListener(() {
      browserModel.save();
    });
    currentWebViewModel.addListener(() {
      browserModel.save();
    });

    var canShowTabScroller =
        browserModel.showTabScroller && browserModel.webViewTabs.isNotEmpty;

    return IndexedStack(
      index: canShowTabScroller ? 1 : 0,
      children: [_buildWebViewTabs(), Container()],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildWebViewTabs() {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          var browserModel = Provider.of<BrowserModel>(context, listen: false);
          var webViewModel = browserModel.getCurrentTab()?.webViewModel;
          var _webViewController = webViewModel?.webViewController;

          if (_webViewController != null) {
            if (await _webViewController.canGoBack()) {
              _webViewController.goBack();
              return false;
            }
          }
          return browserModel.webViewTabs.length == 0;
        },
        child: Listener(
          onPointerUp: (_) {
            FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
            if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus &&
                currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
              currentFocus.focusedChild!.unfocus();
            }
          },
          child: Scaffold(
              appBar: BrowserAppBar(), body: _buildWebViewTabsContent()),
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildWebViewTabsContent() {
    var browserModel = Provider.of<BrowserModel>(context, listen: true);

    var stackChildren = <Widget>[
      IndexedStack(
        index: browserModel.getCurrentTabIndex(),
        children: browserModel.webViewTabs.map((webViewTab) {
          return webViewTab;
        }).toList(),
      ),
    ];
    return Stack(
      children: stackChildren,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Dialog in sense ? Like some pop. I'm right ?

Comment: The code looks fine whats the problem?

Comment: @ProblematicDude if I am no wrong he wants to show the pop-up dialog only once, regardless of how many times the app is run

Comment: I want to create a popup that appears only once to the user. That code now displays nothing. I would like an "example" text that appears only once to the user and asks for confirmation.

Comment: can you show your code how you are displaying the popupdialog?

Comment: Added it but it doesn't work

Comment: That's what I thought. and  You cant do this in init State. As we dont have any context in any init state (and should not have). AND show dialog needs context.

Comment: where should i put that code? can you give me a working example?

Comment: you could do it initstate with slight delay or postframe, With your code I think it should be fine since you already have a delay of 1 sec

Comment: @MaheshJamdade But that will loose the purpose of the OP question. As by that time build will be ready. So better show dialog in the build method

Comment: @FounderOnepiecepower Simply create a bool variable. and show that dialog in build method once and set it false. So next time , check that variable whether to show the dialog or not

Comment: @ProblematicDude it doesn't work. I created the boolean variable but it doesn't work because it doesn't save it in memory. Shared_Preferences doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could invoke your dialog in the build method as @ProblematicDude pointed out

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
      _prefs = prefs;
      isdialogShown = prefs.getBool('dialog_open') ?? false;
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  void showDialogWidget() {
     if (!isdialogShown) {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => AlertDialog(title: Text("Dialog title")),
      );
    });
     isdialogShown = true;
     _prefs.setBool('dialog_open',isdialogShown);
     }
  }

  bool isdialogShown = true;
  SharedPreferences _prefs;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   showDialogWidget();
   return YourWidget();
  }
```

Alternatively if you don't want to call setState in initstate and prevent additional build, then you could move the `showDialogWidget()` in initState inplace of `setState({})`;

Comment: It doesn't work, It said me Non-nullable instance field '_prefs' must be initialized

Comment: have you assigned ```_prefs = prefs;```?

Comment: Try to cut and paste your code, it doesn't work and said me that error

Comment: sure let me check

Comment: I did run this sample code its seems to be running fine just change 
```bool isdialogShown = true;``` have updated the answer

Comment: Dont forget to call setstate in initState after ```isdialogShown``` is assigned a value otherwise the build method won't be called because by the time the ``isdialogShown``` gets assigned build method would be already executed

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. It said me an error on SharedPreferences _prefs; it said me Non-nullable instance field '_prefs' must be initialized and suggest me to put "late" before SharedPreferences but that doesn't work and displays nothing.

Comment: so you mean the Dialog is not visible? I just ran the piece of code that I posted can you add your minimal reproduceable code in the question ?

Comment: i have posted the entire class that i have created

Comment: you are calling  showDialogWidget(); immediately in initstate so it wont work since context wont be available as we did discuss earlier,

Comment: where should i enter it?

Comment: Please check my answer its clearly mentions you should either put it in build() method or 
remove setStatet({}) and replace with showDialogWidget()